# printing even numbers from random generator

Tags: java, random

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exam2_2 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int roll = 0;
        int roll2 = 0;
        int tries = 0;

        while((roll % 2 == 0) && (roll2 % 2 == 0)) {
            roll = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
            roll2 = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
            System.out.println("(" + roll + ", " + roll2 + ")");
            tries++;
        } 
        System.out.println("you won after " + tries + " tries");
    }
}
```

My assignment is to simulate rolling two 8-sided dice and only stop once both numbers are even. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and have tried a bunch of different things to see if it would work the way I need it to work. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think your `while` statement does?

Comment: print out the roll if there isn't a remainder? is that not what it's doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the perfect time to use a `do {} while` to me, something like

```
Random rand = new Random();
int tries = 0;
int roll;
int roll2;
do {
    roll = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
    roll2 = rand.nextInt(8) + 1;
    System.out.printf("(%d, %d)%n", roll, roll2);
    tries++;
} while ((roll % 2 != 0) || (roll2 % 2 != 0)); // <-- while roll or
                                               //     roll2 is odd.
System.out.println("you won after " + tries + " tries");
```

**Or**, You can use [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and replace `((roll % 2 != 0) || (roll2 % 2 != 0))` with

```
while (!((roll % 2 == 0) && (roll2 % 2 == 0)));
```

that is, while **NOT** (`roll` is *even* and `roll2` is *even*).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `while` condition:

```
while( (roll % 2 == 0) && (roll2 % 2 == 0) )
```

That means that while `roll` is even and `roll2` is also even, it'll do the stuff inside that block.

But, you want it to continue looping while their NOT both even, and stop when they are.

So you should change your condition to this:

```
while( !( (roll % 2 == 0) && (roll2 % 2 == 0) ) ) // they're NOT both even
```

or you could do this for better clarity:

```
while( (roll % 2 != 0) || (roll2 % 2 != 0) ) // at least one of them is odd
```

This way, the condition will be `false` when they're both even, thus stopping the loop.